# extract match output using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

i have a sed command to extract binding state free; block of data but this is giving output of binding state active block as well because same keyword in that block also with next and rewind keyword is there any way to match exact keyword for binding state free so that i can get only given block in sed command.

```
lease {

    *****some text******
      binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
    lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
    lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state active;
      next binding state free;
      rewind binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
    lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state active;
      next binding state free;
      rewind binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }




    sed -n '/lease/!b;:a;/}/!{$!{N;ba}};{/binding state free;/p}' file.txt
```

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines (`s/old/new/`), **that is all**. For anything else, e.g. your problem, you should use awk. If you [edit] your question to provide the expected output for that sample input and what you have tried so far then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '/}/{if(flag){print value ORS $0};flag=val=value="";next} /lease/{val=1} val && /^ +binding state free;/{flag=1} {value=value?value ORS $0:$0}'   Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/}/{
  if(flag){print value ORS $0};
  flag=val=value="";
  next}
/lease/{
  val=1}
val && /^ +binding state free;/{
  flag=1}
{
  value=value?value ORS $0:$0}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
lease {

    *****some text******
      binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
    lease {
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
      binding state free;
      *****some text******
      *****some text******
    }
```

Comment: @Vijay, try now and let me know, typo was there.

Comment: @Vijay, code was written as per your shown Input, see I have attached the output which I am getting. Please explain more why it is not working for you??

Comment: its printing  filtered binding state free block 4 times extra

Comment: @Vijay, where? did you see my output? If your Input is different from shown then let me know?

Comment: yes actually i have a log file in log file this is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167332/discussion-between-vijay-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @Vijay, not fair. Codes/solutions could be given only as per provided samples and this works as per your sample shown. If you have extra conditions and do mention them in your post, I will edit my answer then.

Comment: @Vijay, as discussed over chat, code is working as your expectation.

Comment: what to do if i want to delete that extract block

Comment: @Vijay, please open a new thread with new question so that other users who want to learn from this thread will NOT be confuse, thanks.